# how to convert a view to bitmap and conserving the same size of element in android?

Tags: android, view, bitmap

I'm trying to convert a view which contains another inflated view to a bitmap but when execute the code and the see the results it's not the same image that I want,it is wrapping up the elements together .How can i do to keep the view as it is in the bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

If its wrapped in a container than you have to find that child view in the parent view and then grab that view and convert it into a bitmap, not use the parent View.

Comment: you mean i need to convert each child view to a bitmap?

Comment: I thought you had a specific view in mind, but... if you want all children then yes.

Comment: well it's a layout in which i inflated child views,and how could i do that and get them in the right position like they were in the layout?any code?

Comment: Look at the documentation of View, you can grab a parent view's children.

Comment: grabbing view's children is not the problem but after converting them to bitmap how can i garantee that they are positioned in the same place as in the layout

Comment: you have to keep track of all the views and their positioning relative to the parent. Since you are grabbing each specific child (or so it sounds), you have to use that positioning data to handle the drawing on your respective bitmap. My suggestion would to be take this data and then use a canvas and draw all your views on it (relative to the parents data, which should be the size of the canvas) and then convert the canvas into a bitmap.

Comment: still a bit unclear in my mind if you have anything similar please send me the link to get things organized in my head

Comment: There are no links, this is purely theoretical. You have to organize how you're going to do it with respect to the documentation and what is available and how you're going to organize your data.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using?

Did you try View.getDrawingCache() ?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache()

Comment: yes that's the universal method,but i need to convert view & it's children in the same size as original